# SQLite how to refer to column name by a query

Tags: sqlite, relational-database

What I want to do basically is

```
 SELECT (SELECT fields FROM tableB WHERE interest=yes) FROM tableA
```

Why I can not do this?
What could be the workaround?

Example:
I got **tablea** like this

```
time|c1|c2|c3 
---------------
0.0 |1 |11|111
1.0 |2 |22|222
2.0 |3 |33|333
```

**tableb** like this

```
field| interes
--------------
C1   |yes
C2   |yes 
C3   |no
```

I want to be able to put command where like this

```
select (select field from tableb where interest=yes) from tablea  where time=1.0
```

that gives me

```
2|22
```

Heart of the issue is that it does not let me refer to column_names by a query result. :(

Comment: dude, need more info. This is unresolvable...

Comment: Heart of the issue is absence of Normalisation.  c1|c2|c3 is a repeating group, that breaks 2NF.  Place that in a separate file, such that c1|c2|c3 appear as rows, same as Table_B.  Then the code required is simple.

Comment: You mean switch tableA from row to line? But most of the time I also need to do things like select Time,c1 from tableA . This will make it harder no?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing from what little you have written that you want a variable list of fields (where the list of fields is retrieved from `tableB`) to be retrieved from `tableA`.

This isn't possible directly in SQL.  You will need to make 2 calls, the first one to retrieve the list of fields, and the second one where you have generated a SQL statement with an exoplicit list of fields from the first call.

Comment: @user198530 Or you could normalize your data properly. Instead of having `data1`, `data2`, ..., `dataN` columns, make a table with columns `index`, `data` and use a row for each "column". Then you can use joins.